# What wrong with that singleton implementation

Tags: c#, singleton

I wrote static singleton and add class inside the Singleton class.
However, it seem like it broke the pattern.

any advice why?

```
 public sealed class Singleton
    {
        private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
        public int MyProperty { get; set; } = 10;
        static Singleton() { }

        private Singleton() { }

        public static Singleton Instance  {get { return instance; }  }

        public class SecondSingleton
        {
            public Singleton secondInstance;
            public SecondSingleton()
            {
                secondInstance = new Singleton();
                secondInstance.MyProperty = 20;
            }
        }
    }    
    class Program
    {        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Singleton s1 = Singleton.Instance;
            Singleton.SecondSingleton s2 = new  Singleton.SecondSingleton();

            Console.WriteLine($"s1.MyProperty = {s1.MyProperty}");
            Console.WriteLine($"s2.MyProperty = {s2.secondInstance.MyProperty}");
            Console.ReadLine();           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new `Singleton` in `SecondSingleton` constructor, which means `secondInstance != Singleton.Instance`. Instead, you should get the `Instance`, i.e: `secondInstance = Singleton.Instance;`

Comment: But this is the goal of the Singleton, to prevent creation of new instance.
Also, why i am able to call new Singleton(), the private constractor should prevent it.

Comment: `why i am able to call new Singleton()` because `SecondSingleton` is a subclass of `Singleton`, so it have access to its private fields/methods.

Answer (score 1):

Asper WIKI : Singleton restricts the instantiation of a class to one "**single**" instance. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.

The moment you say "SecondInstance", then it is broke the pattern.